# What is the GitLab runner working directory on linux

Tags: gitlab, digital-ocean, gitlab-ci-runner

I have one gitlab runner on digital ocean, i can see my build is passed but am not able to figure out where it cloned my repo, on console of the build shows following

```
Cloning repository... Cloning into **'/builds/.....'**
```

Where is this builds directory on the system?

I followed following documentation for setting up gitlab runner

```
https://about.gitlab.com/2016/04/19/how-to-set-up-gitlab-runner-on-digitalocean/
```

I checked /home/gitlab-runner directory but it's empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the docs you followed you are using a [Docker executor](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/docker.html) meaning that every job that is executed a [given Docker container](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#define-image-and-services-from-gitlab-ci-yml) is started and your job (and thus your clone in the [pre-build phase](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/docker.html#workflow)) and its commands are executed within the Docker container(s).

After the job (success or fail) the Gitlab Runner removes the container(s).

Comment: after posting the question i realized the same, i can see the exited container on the runner machine, but i don't think there is a way to start the container again. i am trying to start the exited container with docker start, but it exits immediately. Could you suggest me a way to start the exited container so that i can get inside the container and check the folder?

Comment: You could try a `docker run -it <container_id> bash`